# How to use Supabase to achieve user online status judgment?

Tags: next.js, supabase

everyone.i am using Supabase and want to achieve real-time user online status judgment.In my profile data table, there is a field: online. i want users to change the value of online to true when starting the browser and connecting to Supabase, and to false when closing the browser.This way, users can check if the other party is online.

dev framework:Next.JS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwVMk.png)

I tried using Supabase Channel before,achieve judgment of the number of online user.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const supabase = createClient()
    const roomOne = supabase.channel('Hall')

    const GetData = async () => {
      const user = await supabase.auth.getUser()

      const userStatus = {
        user: user.data.user?.id,
        online_at: new Date().toISOString(),
      }
      roomOne
        .on('presence', { event: 'sync' }, () => {
          const uniqueUsers = new Set<string>(); 
          for (const id in roomOne.presenceState()) {
            // @ts-ignore
            const user = roomOne.presenceState()[id].user as string; 
            uniqueUsers.add(user); 
          }
          setUserList(Array.from(uniqueUsers)); 
          setOnlineUsers(uniqueUsers.size); 
      })
        .subscribe(async (status) => {
          if (status === "SUBSCRIBED") {
            await roomOne.track(userStatus);
          }
        })
    }
    GetData();

    return () => {
      supabase.removeChannel(roomOne)
      setOnlineUsers(0)
    }
  }, []);
```

However, it is not possible to write to the database after the user closes the browser (offline)

Comment: You don't need to write to the database for this, we have a realtime presence feature to achieve this: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/realtime/presence